# Remove certain tabs from tab control and add a tab at a certain index C#

Tags: c#

I have two tabs that I know the names of (design and picture) and I want to remove every other tab in the tab control. (I want to remove all the tabpages excepts the ones I know the names of.)

I have searched the internet and I found:

```
string tabToRemove = "tabPageName";

for (int i = 0; i < tabControlMain.TabPages.Count; i++)
{
    if (tabControlMain.TabPages[i].Name.Equals(tabToRemove, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
       tabControlMain.TabPages.RemoveAt(i);
       break;
    }
}
```

but this is not what I'm looking for as I do not know the strings of the tabs I want to remove. I only know the names of two.

Comment: Show us what you tried

Comment: MDSN tab control http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx

Comment: I don't get it, you have two tabs in a tabcontrol and you want to remove everyother tab? that doesn't really make sense. Please go in depth when asking a question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming a lot about your question here, but I suppose that you want to remove all the tabpages excepts the ones you know the names.

If it is the case then you fill a list with the known tabpage names (spelled exactly).
Then start a backward loop to remove the tabpages that doesn't fit your requirement.

```
List<string> pagesToKeep = new List<string>() {"Design", "Picture"};
for (int i = tabControlMain.TabPages.Count - 1; i>=0; i--)
{
    string curName = tabControlMain.TabPages[i].Name;
    if(!pagesToKeep.Contains(curName))
    {
        tabControlMain.TabPages.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

The backward loop is required here because when you remove an item from the collection the total number of elements changes and you can't use the end for condition safely.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. This is a great reply although when used, all the items in the tab control, even the design and picture tabs are removed. And yes, you are correct that I want to remove all tab pages except the ones that I know the names of.